# Bind "Enter" key to WXPython Button with Focus

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to make a series of buttons navigable with the arrow keys and enter key.

I have the arrow keys implemented easily enough, but I can't seem to find the answer online how to bind the focused button to the enter key. Specifically I want to be able to use the up/down keys to set the focus to a button, and then hit the enter key to activate the button.

[image: Highlighted button 1]

I can highlight the button i want with the arrows, but the enter key does nothing. Any ideas?

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        frame = wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, )

        self.btn = []
        self.btn.append(wx.Button(self, label='Button 1', id=0))
        self.btn.append(wx.Button(self, label='Button 2', id=1))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1_press, id=0)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.button1_press)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button2_press, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.button2_press)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.on_key)

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)

        self.sizer.Add(self.btn[0], pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.btn[1], pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def button1_press(self, event):
        print 'button 1'

    def button2_press(self, event):
        print 'button 2'

    def on_key(self, event):
        i = self.get_focus()
        if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_DOWN:
            i = min(i+1, 1)
            self.btn[i].SetFocus()
        elif event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_UP:
            i = max(i-1, 0) 
            self.btn[i].SetFocus()
        elif event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_RETURN:  # <-doesn't work
            print 'ENTER!'
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def get_focus(self):
        focused = wx.Window.FindFocus()
        if focused == self.btn[0]:
            return 0
        elif focused == self.btn[1]:
            return 1


class AppMenu(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = Example(None, 'Example')
        frame.Show(True)

        return True

app = AppMenu(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close and to be honest, on my machine (ubuntu 18.04) enter does work but the arrows keys don't.
The key to this appears to be setting `Default()` for the focus within the window.
If you put it all in a `Panel` you get the added benefit of Tab traversval, so tabbing moves between your buttons as well, without any effort on your part.
Here is a version of your code working on my box using python2.7 wx (3.0.2.0) and python 3.6 wx (4.0.3)

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        frame = wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, )
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(200,100))
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 1', id=1)
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Button 2', id=2)
        self.btn1.SetDefault()
        self.btn1.SetFocus()

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0, 0)
        self.sizer.Add(self.btn1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.btn2, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_press)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.on_key)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def button_press(self, event):
        Id = event.GetId()
        print ('Click Button',str(Id))

    def on_key(self, event):
        key = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key == wx.WXK_DOWN or key == wx.WXK_UP:
            i = self.get_focus()
            if i == 1:
                self.btn1.SetDefault()
                self.btn1.SetFocus()
            else:
                self.btn2.SetDefault()
                self.btn2.SetFocus()
            print ('Focus on',str(i))
        elif key == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            print ('ENTER on Button',str(event.GetId()))
        else:
            event.Skip()

    def get_focus(self):
        focused = wx.Window.FindFocus()
        if focused == self.btn1:
            return 2
        elif focused == self.btn2:
            return 1


class AppMenu(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = Example(None, 'Example')
        frame.Show(True)

        return True

app = AppMenu()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Never would have tracked it down the the Panel!