# wxpython toolbarmenu keyboard navigation

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I've been working on an application for blind people, so I decided to python and wxPython for the GUI. The problem is that I cannot navigate the wx.toolbar using tabs. This is my actual code.

```
    menuToolBar = self.CreateToolBar(style=wx.TB_FLAT)
    menuToolBar.AddSeparator()
    menuToolBar.AddTool(ID_NUEVO, "Nuevo Archivo", wx.Bitmap(
        os.path.join(self.__rutaPrincipal, "img/nueva pagina.png")), "Nuevo Archivo")
    menuToolBar.AddSeparator()
    menuToolBar.AddTool(ID_GUARDAR_ARCHIVO, "Guardar Archivo", wx.Bitmap(
        os.path.join(self.__rutaPrincipal, "img/guardar pagina.png")),  "Guardar Archivo")
    menuToolBar.AddTool(ID_ABRIR_ARCHIVO, "Abrir Página", wx.Bitmap(
        os.path.join(self.__rutaPrincipal, "img/abrir pagina.png")), "Abrir Página")
    menuToolBar.AddSeparator()
    menuToolBar.AddTool(ID_FOCUS_PANEL_ESCRITURA, "Foco Escritura", wx.Bitmap(
        os.path.join(self.__rutaPrincipal, "img/panel escritura.png")), "Foco Escritura")
    menuToolBar.AddTool(ID_FOCUS_PANEL_RESULTADO, "Foco Resultado", wx.Bitmap(
        os.path.join(self.__rutaPrincipal, "img/panel resultado.png")), "Foco Resultado")
    menuToolBar.AddSeparator()
    menuToolBar.AddTool(ID_CERRAR_PAGINA, "Cerrar Página", wx.Bitmap(
        os.path.join(self.__rutaPrincipal, "img/cerrar pagina.png")), "Cerrar Página")
    menuToolBar.AddSeparator()

    menuToolBar.Realize()
```

is there any configuration to achieve it? or maybe is there another component that help me?.
P.D. I am new to python development and Stackoverflow

Comment: Without digging into menu event handling, from memory, menus and menu items are navigated with the arrow keys.

Comment: the problem is that I can navigate through the wx.Menu with the arrow keys but when I try to go to the wx.Toolbar it does not take it, neither with the tab nor with the arrow keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than delete the existing anwser, which in fact answers a different question, I'm leaving it in place because I personally believe it's useful, in a related way.

Here is an example of what I was referring to in my comment, about making your own toolbar, which you can navigate using Tab, Left and Right Arrow keys.
It should be enough to get you started.

It uses a normal button and some Generic bitmap buttons, both will work, as we need to illustrate which button currently has focus, which is achieved by using at least 2 different bitmaps for each button. One Normal and one for Focus.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

Valid_keys = [wx.WXK_F1,wx.WXK_RETURN,wx.WXK_TAB,wx.WXK_LEFT,wx.WXK_RIGHT]

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        self.funcs={"Button1":self.OnButton1,
                    "Button2":self.OnButton2,
                    "Button3":self.OnButton3,
                    "Button4":self.OnButton4}
        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Self defined Toolbar", size=(400,400))

        tool_panel = wx.Panel(self,-1,name="tool_panel")
        tool_panel.SetBackgroundColour("lightgreen")
        tool_panel.SetToolTip("Press F1 or Tab to Access Toolbar")

        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(400,300), name="Main_panel")
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("lightblue")

        bmp = wx.Bitmap("Discord.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        bmp1 = wx.Bitmap("Discord1.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        bmp2 = wx.Bitmap("Discord2.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        self.Button1 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(tool_panel,bitmap=bmp,size=(40,40),name="Button1")
        self.Button2 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(tool_panel,bitmap=bmp,size=(40,40),name="Button2")
        self.Button3 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(tool_panel,bitmap=bmp,size=(40,40),name="Button3")
        self.Button4 = wx.Button(tool_panel,-1, label="",size=(40,40),name="Button4")
        self.Button4.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('test.png'))
        self.Button4.SetBitmapFocus(wx.Bitmap('testfocus.png'))

        self.Text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, size=(400,300), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.Button1.SetToolTip("Function1")
        self.Button2.SetToolTip("Function2")
        self.Button3.SetToolTip("Function3")
        self.Button4.SetToolTip("Function4")

        self.BitmapButtons = [self.Button1,self.Button2,self.Button3]
        for i in range(0,len(self.BitmapButtons)):
            self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBitmapLabel(bmp)
            self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBitmapFocus(bmp2)
            self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBitmapSelected(bmp1)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnKey)

        tool_sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        tool_sizer.Add(self.Button1)
        tool_sizer.Add(self.Button2)
        tool_sizer.Add(self.Button3)
        tool_sizer.Add(self.Button4)
        tool_panel.SetSizer(tool_sizer)
        
        main_sizer.Add(tool_panel,0,wx.EXPAND)                
        main_sizer.Add(panel,0,wx.EXPAND,0)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)                
        self.Text.SetFocus() 
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event):
        Id = event.GetId()
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        x = self.funcs[btn.GetName()]
        x()
        self.Text.SetFocus()

    def OnButton1(self):
        print("Button 1")
    def OnButton2(self):
        print("Button 2")  
    def OnButton3(self):
        print("Button 3")
    def OnButton4(self):
        print("Button 4")        

    def OnKey(self, event):
        key = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key not in Valid_keys: #Ignore all keys except F1, Enter and Navigation keys
            event.Skip()
            return
        if key not in [wx.WXK_F1,wx.WXK_RETURN]:
            event.Skip()
            return
        if key == wx.WXK_F1: #F1 focuses on the First Toolbar button 
            self.Button1.SetFocus()
            return
        i = self.get_focus()
        if i == 1:
            id="Button1"
        elif i == 2:
            id="Button2"
        elif i == 3: 
            id="Button3"
        elif i == 4: 
            id="Button4"            
        if i > 0: #Focus was a toolbar button, execute button function
            x = self.funcs[id]
            x()
            self.Text.SetFocus()
        event.Skip()

    def get_focus(self):
        focused = wx.Window.FindFocus()
        if focused == self.Button1:
            return 1
        elif focused == self.Button2:
            return 2
        elif focused == self.Button3:
            return 3
        elif focused == self.Button4:
            return 4            
        else:#Something other than the toolbar buttons has focus return Fail
            return -1
        
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App()
      frame = MainFrame()
      app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

[image][image]
[image]
[image: test.png][image: testfocus.png]

Comment: Thank you so much, it solves my problem, :D

Comment: @diego My pleasure, glad to help. I wish you success with your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `Accelerators` in your `MenuBar` and possibly your `MenuItem`'s.

> An accelerator table allows the application to specify a table of keyboard shortcuts for menu or button commands.

Often, these are set up using the text in the menu item, by-passing the `wx.AcceleratorTable`.

```
p1 = wx.MenuItem(playm, wx.NewIdRef(), '&Play\tCtrl+P')
```

Here the `&Play` sets `P` to be the Menu accelerator, and Ctrl+P to be the hotkey for the function represented by the menu item.
Put another way, when navigating the menus, pressing `P` will select the Play menu item. When not navigating the menus, just pressing Ctrl+P will run that function.
N.B.

- You do not have to setup both.
- Do not place the `&` ampersand character before the same letter more than once in a single menu or the menubar, as only the first one will function.
  e.g. "&Save" and "Sa&ve as" would work, using `S` for "Save" and `V` for "Save as"

> To access the Menu shortcuts Press the `Alt` button and then any of the underlined letters.

Some minimal code with Menu accelerators but no assigned hotkeys:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Setting up the menus
        '''Define main items'''
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        editmenu = wx.Menu()
        infomenu = wx.Menu()
        '''Items'''
        # file menu
        menu_open = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open")
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New")
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save")
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save as")
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit', 'Quit application')
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_PRINT, "&Print")
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_PRINT_SETUP, "Print setup")
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_PREVIEW, "Preview")
        # edit menu
        editmenu.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "Copy")
        editmenu.Append(wx.ID_CUT, "Cut")
        editmenu.Append(wx.ID_PASTE, "Paste")
        editmenu.AppendSeparator()
        editmenu.Append(wx.ID_UNDO, "Undo")
        editmenu.Append(wx.ID_REDO, "Re-do it")
        # info menu
        infomenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About")
        '''Bind items for activation'''
        # bind file menu
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen)

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        # Add menus
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        menuBar.Append(editmenu, "&Edit")
        menuBar.Append(infomenu, "&Help")
        # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnOpen(self, event):
        print ("Menu item selected")
        # event skip as we want to continue checking events in case Quit was chosen
        event.Skip()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Run this code and Press the `Alt` key, press one of the undelined letters F, E or H and navigate the menus using the arrow keys or any underlined letters.

N.B. Certain functions are automatically assigned Hotkeys e.g. Ctrl+Q is Quit.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot to fix my wx.menubar, but the problem is the navigation over **wx.toolbar** component

Comment: @diego My apologies. Somewhere along the way, I fixated on the word `menu` and completely missed `toolbar`. It happens. I'll have another look at it.

Comment: @diego I am unable to find a way to navigate within a toolbar, that is not to say that someone else cannot. The best solution that I can suggest, would be to build your own `panel` containing buttons and position it above your main panel within the frame. To enable button pushes using the Enter key, see the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641315/bind-enter-key-to-wxpython-button-with-focus

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm gonna have a look, maybe is the best option, and do you think i should close the question? as a I mention before, I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @diego No, don't close it. There's a good chance that someone else knows the answer and if not, they may well give you a better idea for a solution than mine. Best of luck to you.